# haystack query for solr to find items where attribute is unset or specified value

Tags: django, python-2.7, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to query solr through haystack for all objects that either does not have an attribute (it's `Null`) or the attribute is a specified value.

I can query solr directly with the snippet `(brand:foo OR (*:* -brand:*))` and get what I want. But I can't find a way to formulate this or anything logically the same through haystack without really ugly hacks.

I did find this ugly hack:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(brand=Raw('%s OR (*:* -brand:*)' % Clean('foo'))
```

But it chains really poorly with that `OR` in there without any parenthesis around it.

Ideally a solution using a pure filter would be best, but failing that a way to add a chainable filter using raw solr query language.

I'm using `django-haystack 2.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect match, but `narrow` helps me enough to let me do what I want

```
SearchQuerySet().narrow('(brand:%s OR (*:* -brand:*))' % Clean('foo'))
```